# Docker image with ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: docker

i'm trying to get Ubuntu 16.04.1 Docker image

lib/ubuntu:16.04 gives me 16.04.5.

is there way to get 16.04.1 image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, point releases on Ubuntu images aren't tagged. Technically you could pick an image tagged by xenial-YYMMDD where the date is from before 16.04.2 was made available.

The question is why you would want to get an outdated image? The difference between 16.04.1 and 16.04.5 is that the latter has more security updates. The libraries remain on the same version so there is no reason to use 16.04.1 instead of the lastest 16.04 update.